# Typescript Date Issue (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, vue.js

Having a very odd issue with Typescript when creating a new Date.

```
<template>
<div> Testing Date</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Test",
  methods: {
    checkDate() {
      console.log("...checkDate...");
      const now = new Date();
      console.log(now);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkDate();
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I'm getting the error:

**This expression is not constructable. Type 'Date' has no construct signatures.**

Is that not a valid means of creating a new instance of a Date object?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you remove the `: Date`?  It's slightly redundant to type a variable if you are going to immediately assign a value to it.  Typescript should be able to infer its style at that point from the assigned value.

Comment: What types do you have configured? It works in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBGIHcBcMAiBDKBTGBeOWCamWAFAJQDcAUEA

Comment: Did you redefine or modify the Date interface? Do you have more code you can share?

Comment: I was going to make the same point. @djneely you shouldn't be typing something when you are assigning a value to it. That's why you have type inference for.

Comment: I do still get the same error if I remove : Date (just a last ditch effort attempt). No I am not redefining the Date with any of my code. The code block as of now is literally just a method that starts out with the above snippet.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce such behavior](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsydeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I have the exact same code on one of my projects and it works. Maybe you import a custom `Date` object or modify/redefine native Date object as @HunterMcMillen says.

Comment: @djneely Can you go to the definition of Date and see if something is redefining it?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen if I follow the link to Date it takes me to node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts

Comment: @djneely hmm okay, can you share your entire Vue component? There has to be some context there that will point out the issue.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen just updated to include the entire component. would like to note that the code does work, but the compiler is complaining (sorry for not noting that earlier)

Comment: I generated another Vue app in the same manner and did some testing and not getting the same issue. While linking through to Date doesn't show anything odd, I may just fire up a new application and migrate stuff over. I'll keep you all posted if I find anything but as of now its a ghost.

Comment: Thank you all for diving in and attempting to help me out. Luckily this is a small project that is still in its early phases too and it was not a huge undertaking to migrate all of this over to a new project. I moved everything over and have not seen this issue again. No idea what happened in the original project. If I install some 3rd party module that borks this again I'll be sure to report back. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth and those that helped here is what I found comparing the new project with the old.

In the old project, if I follow the definition of Date to where it was defined I was directed to the the file: `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts` and the definition was:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    new(value: number | string): Date;
    new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    (): string;
    readonly prototype: Date;
    /**
     * Parses a string containing a date, and returns the number of milliseconds between that date and midnight, January 1, 1970.
     * @param s A date string
     */
    parse(s: string): number;
    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970 Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) (or GMT) and the specified date.
     * @param year The full year designation is required for cross-century date accuracy. If year is between 0 and 99 is used, then year is assumed to be 1900 + year.
     * @param month The month as a number between 0 and 11 (January to December).
     * @param date The date as a number between 1 and 31.
     * @param hours Must be supplied if minutes is supplied. A number from 0 to 23 (midnight to 11pm) that specifies the hour.
     * @param minutes Must be supplied if seconds is supplied. A number from 0 to 59 that specifies the minutes.
     * @param seconds Must be supplied if milliseconds is supplied. A number from 0 to 59 that specifies the seconds.
     * @param ms A number from 0 to 999 that specifies the milliseconds.
     */
    UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): number;
    now(): number;
}

declare var Date: Date;
```

In the above code block `declare var Date: Date;` appears to be the culprit.

In the new project if I follow the Date defintion I'm sent to: `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts` (exact same file) but the definition for Date is now:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    new(value: number | string): Date;
    new(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): Date;
    (): string;
    readonly prototype: Date;
    /**
     * Parses a string containing a date, and returns the number of milliseconds between that date and midnight, January 1, 1970.
     * @param s A date string
     */
    parse(s: string): number;
    /**
     * Returns the number of milliseconds between midnight, January 1, 1970 Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) (or GMT) and the specified date.
     * @param year The full year designation is required for cross-century date accuracy. If year is between 0 and 99 is used, then year is assumed to be 1900 + year.
     * @param month The month as a number between 0 and 11 (January to December).
     * @param date The date as a number between 1 and 31.
     * @param hours Must be supplied if minutes is supplied. A number from 0 to 23 (midnight to 11pm) that specifies the hour.
     * @param minutes Must be supplied if seconds is supplied. A number from 0 to 59 that specifies the minutes.
     * @param seconds Must be supplied if milliseconds is supplied. A number from 0 to 59 that specifies the seconds.
     * @param ms A number from 0 to 999 that specifies the milliseconds.
     */
    UTC(year: number, month: number, date?: number, hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number, ms?: number): number;
    now(): number;
}

declare var Date: DateConstructor;
```

The `DateConstructor` interface appears to be the same but the `declare var Date: DateConstructor;` appears to be the correct implementation.

So, again, no idea what happened with this. I do not play around in the core files so not sure how this file got 'corrupted?'. Thanks again for everyone who jumped in on this so quickly.

Comment: You should highlight the differences, I can only see a difference in the last line. It's also not clear which is correct or should be used.